# Replay Ping back AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am just making IRC in actionscript 3, but now i have a little problem with Socket. Connections are fine, but i get disconnect when i don't replay ping back, so my question is how can i create pong in AS3? I did search for some tutorials, but i cant find all and some explains isnt fine to understand. If anyone can help me on good way.
Thanks!

So far as i am:

```
var servername:String = "irc.example.com"; 

var portnumber:int = 6667; 

var _sock:Socket = new Socket(); 

_sock.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);

_sock.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onSocketData);

_sock.connect(servername, portnumber);

function onConnect(evt:Event):void {     
    tServerInfo.text = "Verbinden met " + servername;     
}

function onSocketData(event:ProgressEvent):void {     
    var socketdata:String;     
        while(_sock.bytesAvailable) {         
            socketdata = _sock.readUTFBytes(_sock.bytesAvailable);
            tServerInfo.text = socketdata;         
        }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ping, or keep-alive messages aren't anything special; they're just normal messages, sent on a schedule. You just need to set up a `Timer` to send a ping message (can be anything) every, say 15 seconds or so, in order to keep the Socket open, otherwise it'll close down as it's not being used.

You also need a small bit of code to ignore these messages when you're reading them, but it's trivial.

Comment: @divilysausages Thanks for your answer! Can you show me a little example how i need to write it?